# How to download the google drive file content and save into corresponding file format using PHP

Tags: php, file, google-drive-api

I am working on a google drive application where i need to download the content and write the content into corresponding format (Eg: word,Excel or ppt) using PHP API. Please note that files are not in native format so there wont be a download Url.I am using export link for downloading the content. I am creating the files in google drive document,sheet and slide formats.

Below is my code

```
$file = $service->files->get($fileId);            
$downloadUrl = $file['exportLinks']['application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.wordprocessingml.document'];
if ($downloadUrl) {
  $request = new Google_HttpRequest($downloadUrl, 'GET', null, null);
  $httpRequest = Google_Client::$io->authenticatedRequest($request);              
  if ($httpRequest->getResponseHttpCode() == 200) {   
      $response = $httpRequest->getResponseBody();
  } else {
    // An error occurred.
    return null;
  }
} else {
  return null;
}
```

Everything is working and i am getting the response also as below.

```
Google_HttpRequest Object
(
    [batchHeaders:Google_HttpRequest:private] => Array
        (
            [Content-Type] => application/http
            [Content-Transfer-Encoding] => binary
            [MIME-Version] => 1.0
            [Content-Length] => 
        )

    [url:protected] => https://docs.google.com/feeds/download/documents/export/Export?id=1aKI7o3g-eLNuLV7dAc-gS5oakhkwl3dLfVPaBBJX0Y4&exportFormat=docx
    [requestMethod:protected] => GET
    [requestHeaders:protected] => Array
        (
            [authorization] => Bearer ya29.IAHncRF0XeCjbX967QqIOb3IDVfowGgmmSC6SDssBW1yFXdfX4MlxbcqOB21CRW1HmVtyqMfC1QzgQ
        )

    [postBody:protected] => 
    [userAgent:protected] => google-api-php-client/0.6.5
    [responseHttpCode:protected] => 200
    [responseHeaders:protected] => Array
        (
            [content-type] => application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.wordprocessingml.document; charset=utf-8
            [x-robots-tag] => noarchive
            [content-disposition] => attachment;filename="asd.docx"
            [set-cookie] => NID=67=W-YZgqChz2SoodlmbjJDk9WpVdCFMg9Z-mX2KgBxZrYyUUix0aXfKtVMnwZm6XQ4UOZG7NpHEC6XRwbMgTft4nAMQFQHUV4Z-9L1dEWkSlmKIoJLJhyyGhVQeh0r20Vz;Domain=.google.com;Path=/;Expires=Sat, 22-Aug-2015 07:36:01 GMT;HttpOnly
            [p3p] => CP="This is not a P3P policy! See http://www.google.com/support/accounts/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=151657 for more info."
            [date] => Fri, 20 Feb 2015 07:36:01 GMT
            [expires] => Fri, 20 Feb 2015 07:36:01 GMT
            [cache-control] => private, max-age=0
            [x-content-type-options] => nosniff
            [x-frame-options] => SAMEORIGIN
            [x-xss-protection] => 1; mode=block
            [server] => GSE
            [transfer-encoding] => chunked
            [alternate-protocol] => 443:quic,p=0.08
        )

    [responseBody:protected] => PK€¼SFdocProps/app.xmlÁ
Â0D¿À¹kªI[Ñ«õ’m
´»!»Šþ½A={Þð˜±í}Ô
2GÂZÏg•V€žBÄ¾Ö§ãnºÒŠÅap!Ôú¬Ûfb™d‰Àªk}IkcØ_`t<+é(NJÌ½¡®‹¶ä¯# ˜EU-
Ü0@˜¦P¿ë›ü+
ä_ûø||¤âkì&¥!z'åd³'êP¥ÃÖük¾§š'PKoð„¬PK€¼SFdocProps/core.xmlmÏJÄ@‡ŸÀw(soÓ® RÚîÍ“‚
^‡LìÛùÃ$ÚîÛ;[´
î1ù}ùHÒí7Ÿ”Øß«¦ªUAƒ±~ìÕëËCy¯
íž‚§^‰Õ~¸é0¶=¥)‰%.²Ès‹±WG‘Ø0Éi®2ásø’Ó’Ë4BÔxÒ#Á®®ïÀ‘h£EÃEXÆÍ¨¾•7eüHÓ*04‘#/MÕÀ/+”_X“?¤³rŽtý    7za»ó¯§–Ö_^…¤†Î`+V&4›Ê\:ØZüûÞðPK}Š·–â‰PK€¼SFword/numbering.xml¥’Anƒ0EOÐ; ïHU…B³hÔnºk{€‰1`ÅöXcÍíë„-•*JWÆÿýïáowZE 'Ñdl³NX$Ç\š2cïoO«{9&…Fdì$Û=ÜlÛÔÔú (œ‹Â¸TóŒUÞÛ4Ž¯„·F+LH|x¥2Ö@ÇÚ®8j^¤’þß&É»b0c5™ôŠXiÉ  þ,I±($×G¯ 9¾d¼ÖÂø‹cLB…h\%­ëiz)-«Òüv‰F«þ\kç¸åmØ³VQ‹”[B.œ_÷Ýp n’<#Åœß=û$¤0çvL@ƒ÷:x_—vAwáÔœ ÝèEèô3,ØçW½•³ZüRk ]m'µ/·RI¿ï“äuÌXM&í-9¡ÃÂ$)…ä¢ûô
ã{’¬×ZtŒI¨ÐWIëzš¾•ŠUi~;D£U¿¯µcÜr‚6Ü…V'£)·„\8VW§â@œ%#x@Š1-üôì;Ñ Í€9$ã4xOƒw7´#ê|ó,œÓÈ©ô&·´¿în˜çw½•£R|A*_ÓÈ[¼ò=@ÝBPÈw"ÓÀæ¼çR.¡$Ðçº?Ýì,¹ˆËº+Î´ò´WÂÚ²E÷úDmj@‡èmHlëÀóÑûšÅWå'’ ëq÷j-¾PK-ldv÷PK€¼SFword/styles.xmlíWíNÛ0}‚½C”ÿ¦”lª(¨±MblÝ8ŽÓxulËvZº§ŸoLY“R4ÆÚ?é½ö=××çøÆ9»¸O‰³DBbF'®íÃöéí¿Êvbƒ>Äb_‚Xìôï×Ý‰žaUÜÅ·±\L|ïû³ëÕHä…¾ÉGÏÿ&ZwY¨ºŠ°žû/éÐ\äÿ;%úÏUâ-Ø—«òü7PKå 7.bPK€¼SFword/document.xmlíXKnÛ0=Aï@pËv"0âdQ#Ý4…§“#‰
 );îª§éÁz’R_§NR¸Ð6€´HçÍã›)èüò^I²Fç…Ñ3:)AÍ:›ÑÏ·W'g”øšƒ4gt‹ž^^¼9ßL¹a…BHDÐ~ªØŒæ!Øi’x–£?0u4¦Æ)±ë²D»+ì  3ÊB+!EØ&ãáðm`ÌŒNOˆ%˜3Þ¤¡t™š4›Gëá‰[»ÌÊUÄÄ¡ŒŒö¹°¾ESÇ¢EcÞ‚¬·ˆµ’í¼=$w°‰éP²´1Ž[gzGçµ±C
°„è<¡ðkÌ–‰¡;˜²8ö€ºØƒ»­‚Ú-d§…—‡©MÅÊÛ>fGèùÐßŠƒªx!z…ÂuyËÁ…@ƒ 
»CþôºbæÙAå¼‡ÄdÔ®Hýev4Ü+—ewhÙËÐ>8SXz7 °»,ö4'›)3ÒÄàªºhRÙ
ß–OÍqã‹6m†nî‰ÁÇCs”OÌ›c
…,U¸…+Þ‹tã\)4Þ2¾PSzC°\¶WSe§"ÍŒx
Ë`
²±'¼{Ñ
*„(Èý¥ÚÙ«uDzÖ¡G·FzÐ²wûñíû`0(}CðW(ÖJMú4÷öööö¾LÃg½+!‘ 9YmÉ2~úûœMÆcr:ÉâšôàëKx¯a¯áÿ á³çx/ž÷›ÌëKn¯á_:™ãyœ:ÁaK¾@<šßþÛ—Å#õ|›-¿F‡ÍŒŽÆãI…ŸÇöéÙ¤‘Ùf×P²“˜Æü&õ'²üA7»ë¬LF5ýãS¡n·£Õp¥gC®e’´¿E’ÝÜ‹ŸPKäÃ¶ƒ¯PK€¼SFword/_rels/document.xml.rels­’ÍJ1€ŸÀwsw³mEDšíE
½Êúivö‡&“LÅ}{£`°à‚‡=†!ß÷1Ìþðá¬xÇ˜&O
6U
Éøn¢AÁ[{¼‘XS§­'T0c‚Cs·E«9ÿIã’ÈJ
Fæð,e2#:*ò¤÷ÑiÎÏ8È ÍE(·uý(ão47LÑê8 +è=q«Ï«ŒÑÎÿ#ò}?|ñæêøŸ,`§NAÇM6ÞkÈhc¨Åu5
‹Z¼ÍžË;Q ©`”‹j±“ñÕh¶M€‹ÖbI”î¥D½¯°Š    Wš˜½"þÌ™”~W7Ãá­Ô1*©õãÑ#4jå¨xÚðq’Á¡(ºÆ6«*%gµ"®Ëu0_RÊ}BÅÊ].mÂ7y4¡­|°×½òd²5PLU¦å¹K~Äl¤‰zåYY¶9Â›Æjèõ­[ÊQ"Ü»ª¯xeÃàÒÖ^ž¢ó=ßpäLÍ\ž ·>V~™U—‡è­OA°|šcBÉaF€vC
˜’9d²§o¡ÏÖ1ÿâ¦Uÿ0±[; â©üÇâír÷£PKÈ¤›£H¨PK€¼SFoð„¬docProps/app.xmlPK€¼SF}Š·–â‰êdocProps/core.xmlPK€¼SF'œ±ÝX»word/numbering.xmlPK€¼SFˆê¢H©ˆ£word/settings.xmlPK€¼SF-ldv÷‹word/fontTable.xmlPK€¼SFå 7.bAword/styles.xmlPK€¼SFäÃ¶ƒ¯à
word/document.xmlPK€¼SFin’øß¨Î
word/_rels/document.xml.relsPK€¼SF/]ãM÷_rels/.relsPK€¼SFÈ¤›£H¨[Content_Types].xmlPK

|œ
    [accessKey] => 
)
```

How do i decode the responseBody into original format and write into a file. Please provide some sample code. I need to do this same for below export format also

1. application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.presentationml.presentation
2. application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet

Thanks

Comment: The response shows that the  "[Content-Type] => application/http". Try changing it to "application/json" in the request header. Also could you try doing the same request manually using cURL?

Answer (score 1):

I know am late but this will help someone. I spend a whole day trying to figure out the same problem. What happens is that the browser can't translate the response so you can't get to see what the response have. All you do is

```
file_put_contents('BULK/Sample_08_TemplateCloneRow.docx',$httpRequest->getResponseBody());
```